# React-admin dynamic resource

Tags: reactjs, resources, jsx, react-admin

I have resource for user, instructor , classrooms

And have their list, create, edit page

But now I want that when we click on list of classroom it will open another list with all  user enrolled in classroom
And it will have btns to AddStudents and AddClassroom
So I want to store this list in custom resource

Comment: can you please add some code, and what you've done so far, so that we can help you out.

Comment: please look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69986884/in-react-admin-while-creating-dynamic-resources-uselocation-and-usehistory-h