# In react-admin , while creating dynamic resources - useLocation and useHistory hooks are not working

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In React-admin , I am implementing dynamic resource
this file return my resource as object ,

In this component react-router-dom hooks giving error and undefined

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import RoomList from "../components/Room";

const AdminResources = () => {
  const [resourceToBeLoaded, setResourceToBeLoaded] = React.useState("");
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();
  const resourceName = location?.pathname;
  let id = "";
  console.log(history, location);
  if (resourceName) {
    const roomId = resourceName.split("/")[2];
    id = roomId;
  }
  console.log(id, resourceName);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const obj = {
      [`/room/${id}`]: {
        name: `room/${id}`,
        list: RoomList,
      },
    };
    if (obj[resourceName]) {
      setResourceToBeLoaded(obj[resourceName]);
    }
  }, [resourceName, id]);
  console.log(resourceToBeLoaded, "BEFORE SENDING");
  return resourceToBeLoaded;
};

export default AdminResources;
```

my app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Admin, Resource } from "react-admin";

import MyLoginPage from "./pages/MyLoginPage";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import customRoutes from "./customRoutes";
import MyLayout from "./components/Layout/MyLayout";


import ClassroomPage from "./pages/ClassroomPage";

import authProvider from "./utils/authProvider";
import dataProvider from "./utils/dataProvider";
import AdminResources from "./AdminResources";


function App() {
  return (
    <Admin
      dashboard={HomePage}
      loginPage={MyLoginPage}
      customRoutes={customRoutes}
      authProvider={authProvider}
      layout={MyLayout}
      dataProvider={dataProvider("http://localhost:5000/org")}
      disableTelemetry
    >
      <Resource name="classroom" {...ClassroomPage} />
      {AdminResources && <Resource {...AdminResources()} />}
     
    </Admin>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ERROR :-
hooks.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location') at useLocation (hooks.js:29) at AdminResources (index.js:8) at App (App.js:35)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example code made me realize what I did wrong myself. The way you have written the component `useLocation` will be called outside the scope of the `<Admin>` component. The Admin component supplies the context needed for that hook.

So bellow is how I would change your code to fix that particular issue. However, I didn't understand the intention of the code in AdminResources so I left that out. Felt out of scope for the useLocation issue.

```
const AdminResources = () => {
  const [resourceToBeLoaded, setResourceToBeLoaded] = React.useState(null);
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();
  const resourceName = location?.pathname;
  /* ... TODO populate resourceToBeLoaded ... */
  return resourceToBeLoaded ? <Resource {...resourceToBeLoaded} /> : null;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <Admin
      dashboard={HomePage}
      loginPage={MyLoginPage}
      customRoutes={customRoutes}
      authProvider={authProvider}
      layout={MyLayout}
      dataProvider={dataProvider("http://localhost:5000/org")}
      disableTelemetry
    >
      <Resource name="classroom" {...ClassroomPage} />
      <AdminResources />
     
    </Admin>
  );
}
```

(I realize this is very old but hope it will help next person who ends up here.)